# How to redirect a 404 to home

Tags: html

searching to redirect a page which does not exist to home or change 404 error page.
How can i do that?

I just want to change how 404 error is show to make a better user experience.

Comment: 404 page has its own importance if the user wants to access the page that doesn't exist then 404 pages confirms the user that there is no page like this. If 404 page redirect to home page then I think it will effect User Exprience

Comment: You can have a big button in the center to redirect to the home page on 404 pages It will satisfy user that page doesn't exist whose user is searching.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment above, this really disrupts the user experience, it is better to substitute a page for "no content found" or something. But if you still want to make a redirect, catch the response from the server in index.php, try this:

```
if (http_response_code() == 404) {
        header( "Location: /" );
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Note: the OP didn't specify they were using PHP in this case.